# Unable to run SASS in Webstorm

Tags: sass, webstorm

I just installed Sass using Ruby Gems, although my project is in NodeJS in Webstorm. To enable the SASS file watcher in Webstorm. When I run "sass styles.scss" from the commandline, I get  a `.sass-cache` folder but not the actual compiled CSS file. Webstorm does not show any errors in my SASS file. I need the file to compile to a .css file.

I am also trying to setup a  filewatcher in Webstorm that is not compiling the scss file. My SCSS executable path in the filewatcher in Webstorm is this. C:\Ruby200-x64\bin\sass.bat.

Here are the filewatcher settings.

[image]

The error Webstorm shows in the console, when the .scss file is saved is (which is when the file watcher should be triggered), is this:

```
C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/sass.bat --no-cache --update styles.scss:styles.css
'"ruby.exe"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

The full argument to the file watcher that cant be entirely seen in the image above is this:

```
--no-cache --update $FileName$:$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css
```

Comment: You don't have to use cmd/terminal to use (ruby) sass watchers. Just open watchers, select (in case of ruby install) path to sass.bat. After that just check name of that watcher and your ready to go. Check for your .css in dropdown from .scss file (default).

Comment: @Drops Thanks! I tried that. But now, the console in Webstorm says; `'"ruby.exe"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.` Should I try changing it to "ruby" in the bat file. I just installed Ruby and its new to for me - so I don't want to break anything in the default install.

Comment: @Drops - And the sass-cache folder that I mentioned above is what I get when I try to do the compile from the commandline.

Comment: @EC, hmmm. You don't need ruby.exe for this. I have two machines and tried with Ruby 32 and 64 bit (for win) 'cause I had some issues and made it work on both. So its not that. Have you installed sass via cmd or built-in terminal in ***storm?

Comment: @Drops I installed Ruby and Sass from the Windows CMD as directed here: http://sass-lang.com/install. I've posted more details above. Thanks.

Comment: You don't have to touch ruby install, everything is done through ***storm GUI. In watcher options put path to sass.bat(not sass, scss.bat or scss) (I wrote you my path in some of previous answers) and that's it. It should work out of the box if you leave defaults.

Comment: @Drops How would you get a sass.bat without installing ruby and gem

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was that after the installs of ruby and sass you are done with them. I'll post you screenshots of my watcher in answer and if you done everything as I said in previous answer (for node-sass) it really should "just" work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here it is:

[image]

Didn't numerate but from top to bottom,

1. Select you watcher, you can make presets for various situations (Maybe try to make a new one)
2. Path to my 32bit sass.bat (not 100% sure but I think that even scss.bat worked)
3. Output, you can see in screenshot below how it should work/look.

[image]

Comment: That worked! Thanks. Although I'm not really seeing any minification in the output css. How can I get that?

Comment: just add '--style compressed' to 'Arguments'

Comment: There is a video explaining the [process](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hUEgcBCxrQE). Thanks to Fedor Korotkov