# Add SASS file watcher to phpStorm

Tags: sass, phpstorm, file-watcher

I'm trying to add SASS support to phpStorm, but I can not find SASS or SCSS file watchers in Settings menu.

All I can add as a new file watcher are listed below:

- Closure Compile
- CSSO CSS Optimizer
- Traceur compiler
- TypeScript
- UgliftJS
- YUI Compressor CSS
- YUI Compressor JS

Should I install some updates to phpStorm or add some plugins?

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23865632/unable-to-run-sass-in-webstorm/23867100#23867100) and [possible duplicate 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23732228/sass-filewatcher-for-webstorm/23806302#23806302)

Comment: Do you have standard SASS plugin enabled? I also do not see LESS in your list. If those standard/bundled plugins disabled then yes -- you may need to re-enable them.

Comment: LazyOne, you are right! I forgot to enable those plugins! Thanks a lot for your help!